# Assertion in MEX file causes Matlab to crash

Tags: c++, matlab-engine

I'm using the `mxAssert`-macro defined by **matrix.h** in my C++ code which mex perfectly compiles. When an assertion is violated in my called mex code, this assertion causes not my program to crash but Matlab itself. Am I missing something out? Is that intended behavior?
When I look at Matlab's crash report, the causing assertion is the very same raised by my code - including my descriptive description... Do I have to run my mex code in a certain way so that Matlab can recognize mex code caused assertions (similar to try-catch)?
Probably there's another way to safely stop my mex code and return to the Matlab prompt.

Thank you in advance, any help is very appreciated!

EDIT: the code is compiled with the command `mex -v Temp.cpp -g`

EDIT: a minimal example that brings my matlab to its knees:

```cpp
#include <matrix.h>
class Temp {
public:
    Temp();
    virtual ~Temp();
};

Temp::Temp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

Temp::~Temp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

extern "C" {
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    int foo = 10;
    mxAssert(foo==11, "foo is not 10");
}
}
```

Comment: This should not happen. Assertion failure should bring you back to the matlab command line. Try a simple minimal mex first and post the code if it still fails.

Answer (score 2):

On my system (Ubuntu 64), it crashes too.

I guess it makes senss, because that's what assert is supposed to do.

I strongly advise you to use something like:

```
if(error){mexErrMsgTxt("assert failed\n");}
```

Otherwise, one of my friends have the following trick (with preprocessor instructions):

```
#define assert( isOK )       ( (isOK) ? (void)0 : (void) mexErrMsgTxt("assert failed\n") )
```

To print individual error strings, e.g. `myassert(A=B,"A not B")` , you can enhance this a little bit:

```
#define myassert( isOK,astr )      ( (isOK) ? (void)0 : (void) mexErrMsgTxt(astr) )
```

He also told me that you can improvie it using something like:

```
#isOK,__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__
```

...in order to print the line number and so on.

Comment: How is it possible to pass the preprocessor variables like line number etc. to the `mexErrMsgTxt`?

Comment: @JaBe, good question. Maybe you could make a new C++ question about it.

Comment: yes see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630530/how-to-print-c-preprocessor-variables-like-line-with-mexerrmsgtxt-in-matla