# How to print C-preprocessor variables like __LINE__ with mexErrMsgTxt() In Matlab MEX

Tags: c++, c, debugging, mex, c-preprocessor

For debugging Matlab-MEX, which can be quite a hassle, it would be nice to have better assertion capabilities. Following [this question about mex-assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492761/assertion-in-mex-file-causes-matlab-to-crash/9311121), it is possible to define a preprocessor makro, that throws an error to Matlab and prints a string (can mostly replace `mxAssert`, which unfortunately crashes Matlab2011b).

```
#define myassert( isOK,astr )      ( (isOK) ? (void)0 : (void) mexErrMsgTxt(astr) )
```

It would be much nicer to print the file, line number and caller function, from where following example assertion `myassert(A=B,"A not B")` is raised! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492761/assertion-in-mex-file-causes-matlab-to-crash/9311121#9311121) to the initial question states that they are the preprocessor variables:

```
__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__
```

**How can we print these preprocessor variables with `mexErrMsgTxt`?**

The problem is, that `mexErrMsgTxt()` takes a char* argument and not multiple inputs like for example `printf(const char *format, ...)`.

My thinking goes only so far at the moment:

1. It's not possible to build a function, because the preprocessor variables will have the values (e.g. line number) from the function.
2. It was not possible for me to write a working multiline preprocessor makro that creates a `char` from the passed `string astr` and passes it to `mexErrMsgTxt()`. [Maybe a solution is along these lines.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204202/is-it-possible-to-print-a-preprocessor-variable-in-c)
3. A *hybrid* solution with a char creating preprocessor makro and a function that passes it to `mexErrMsgTxt()` doesn't feel like good coding practice.

It would be really nice to make the specified error string optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenating preprocessor tokens works as long as you only use `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and a string literal as message. Then you can write something like

```
#define STRINGIZE_I(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) STRINGIZE_I(x)

#define myassert(isOK, astr) ( (isOK) ? (void)0 : (void) mexErrMsgTxt(__FILE__ ":" STRINGIZE(__LINE__) ": " astr) )
```

Unfortunately, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is not a string literal even for those compilers who support it. If you want to use it (or less fixed error messages), you'll have to assemble the string dynamically, which means something along the lines of

```
#define myassert(isOK, astr)                                            \
  do {                                                                  \
    if(!(isOk)) {                                                       \
      std::ostringstream fmt;                                           \
      fmt << "In " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ", "                       \
          << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ": " << (astr);             \
      (void) mexErrMsgTxt(fmt.str().c_str());                           \
    }                                                                   \
  } while(false)
```

For C, do the same with `snprintf`. (Or `asprintf`. It avoids problems with fixed buffer lengths and long error messages, and it is about as portable as `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`). Either way, roughly like

```
#define myassert(isOK, astr)                                            \
  do {                                                                  \
    if(!(isOk)) {                                                       \
      char buf[ENOUGH_SPACE];                                           \
      snprintf(buf, ENOUGH_SPACE, "In %s, %s:%d: %s",                   \
               __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, (astr));        \
      buf[ENOUGH_SPACE - 1] = '\0';                                     \
      (void) mexErrMsgTxt(buf);                                         \
    }                                                                   \
  } while(0)
```

...where `ENOUGH_SPACE` would have to be defined appropriately (in the `snprintf` case).

Comment: Thank's for that large answer! ;) The string is optional already... Is the (void) command in front of `mexErrMsgTxt` and in front of `0` really necessary? Or is it just coding practice to clarify that there is no output?

Comment: `mexErrMsgTxt` returns `void`, and both result operands of `?:` have to have the same type, so it's necessary in this construct (which I cargo-culted from the question). As for coding practice: If I had written it myself, I'd have used `do { if(!(isOk)) { mexErrMsgTxt(all that stuff); } } while(0)` because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros